# Test Suites vs Tests

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I ran all jest unit tests. The results are in the image below. What is the difference between a test suite & a test? Is a **Test Suite** equivalent to a test class and a **Test** equivalent a test method in Apex?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much. If we go into details they are not equivalent (one test.js can contain several suites) but to simplify things they can be treated as equivalent